# Accessibility service remove icon when user close needed application

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice, talkback, accessibility

I use Accessibility service to draw icon over Google Photos app and do it with the next code:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
    info.packageNames = new String[] {"com.google.android.apps.photos"};
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    setServiceInfo(info);
```

But when user close app or hide it, icon lefts. I didn't find any event which can handle this case. Could anybody please help me with this. I want draw icon only for some apps and remove it after user close this app.

UPDATE

I used AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED event and got package name by event, but from Android N when my icon is drawn, AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED happens with my own package name and icon is removed.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to draw an icon sometimes, and remove it other times. And you're having trouble knowing when to remove and when to add your icon?

Comment: @ChrisCM I want draw some icon when apps with needed package names is opened and remove icon when such apps is closed.

Comment: There's not enough information here. You should add a bit of code that shows when you call your "addIcon" function and when you call your "removeIcon" function. Right now we can only speculate on when you're doing this. For example: it would appear to me that you call add/remove non-discriminantly when you get window state changed events from the com.google.... package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code to get events for all apps:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
config.notificationTimeout = 100;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
  //Just in case this helps
  config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;
}
setServiceInfo(config);
```

Then I filter apps in `onAccessibilityEvent` method:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
  try { // Try to avoid Security exceptions (Seen in Play Console)
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
      if (event.getPackageName() != null && event.getClassName() != null) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
          event.getPackageName().toString(),
          event.getClassName().toString()
        );
        // check componentName and do what you want
      }
    }
  }
}
```